# Retain chosen values after reuploading a file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this code that will get the values selected when the user clicks a button that will reupload a file. I tried using window.name but the data is still lost, i might going at this at a wrong angle but i hope you can help me. is there a way for myVal to not be emptied once the file is uploaded again? the uploading and the select values belong to different forms, i cant just use array since that would mean i should submit the form where the select values are.

thank you

```
function testcsv()
    {
        var myVal = $('#csv_map').find('.sqlopt').map(function() {
                                       return $(this).val();

                                       }).get().join(',');
        var select_val = myVal.split(',');

        alert(select_val);
        window.name = myVal;


        $('#csvtest').click(
        function()
        {
        $('#csv_form').submit();
        alert(window.name);
        }
        );

        // $('#sqlbox_1').val(test[0]);


    }
```

Comment: Please do not create unecessary global variables (`window.name`)...

Comment: i know, i'm sorry. i was desperate. and i read somewhere that window.name is a good way for this to work. what would you suggest @ThiefMaster?

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden field inside your upload form and update it right before the form is submitted (i.e. when user uploads a file). Prototype:

```
<!-- Upload form -->
<form id="csv_form">
<!-- form definition omitted (fields, labels, etc) ... -->

<!-- and this is our hidden field -->
<input type="hidden" name="select_val" />
</form>

<!-- Form with SELECTs -->
<form id="csv_map">
<select class="sqlopt"> ... </select>
<select  class="sqlopt"> ... </select>
<!-- rest of the form definition omitted ... -->
</form>

<!-- Put this JS somewhere -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#csv_form').submit(function() {
    var myVal = $('#csv_map').find('.sqlopt').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');

    // Update value of hidden field 
    $(this).find('input[name="select_val"]').val(myVal); // will contain comma-separated string of values
  });
});
</script>
```